# How can I listen for a button press in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter, listener

How can I listen for a button press in Tkinter? I need to listen for a button and not run a function but, I want to run a function that listens for a button.

**Update**
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import thread

from Tkinter import *

class at(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **params):
    ## Standard heading: initialization
    apply(Frame.__init__, (self,) + args, params)
    self._parent = None
    if len(args) != 0: self._parent = args[0]
    self._init_before()
    self.v = StringVar()
    ## Widget creation
    self._widgets = {}
    self._widgets['button#1'] = Button(self, name='button#1', text='up',)
    self._widgets['button#1'].grid(column=1, row=1)
    self._widgets['entry#1'] = Entry(self, name='entry#1', textvariable=self.v)
    self._widgets['entry#1'].grid(column=2, row=1)
    self._widgets['button#2'] = Button(self, name='button#2', text='down',)
    self._widgets['button#2'].grid(column=1, row=2)
    ## Scroll commands
    ## Resize behavior(s)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=0, minsize=30)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=0, minsize=31)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0, minsize=30)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=0, minsize=65)
    self.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    ## Call to post-init method
    self._init_after()

  def _init_before(self):
    self._init_specificBefore()

  def _init_after(self):
    self._init_specificAfter()

  def u(self):
    if self.listening==True:
        self.u=True
        self.listening=False

  def d(self):
    if self.listening==True:
        self.d=True
        self.listening=False

  def listen(self):
    #listen for self.u and self.d

  def _init_specificBefore(self):
    pass

  def _init_specificAfter(self):
        range=[0,100]
    current_guess=range[1]/2
    n=1
    x=""
    while 1:
    self.v.set(str(current_guess)+"?")
    x=self.listen()
    if x=="u":
        range[0]=current_guess
        if range[0]==0:
            current_guess=round(current_guess+round(range[1]/2))
        else:
            current_guess=round(current_guess+round((range[1]-range[0])/2))
    elif x=="d":
        range[1]=current_guess
        if range[0]==0:
            current_guess=round(round(range[1]/2))
        else:
            current_guess=range[0]+(round((range[1]-range[0])/2))
    elif x=="y":
        print "It took me "+str(n)+" guesses."
        break
    n=n+1



if __name__ == '__main__':
  root = Tk()
  o = at(root)
  o.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What?!? Sounds a bit like something the cat in a hat would say when learning python... I take it you're looking for some sort of event loop?

Comment: It sounds like you want to create your own event loop, but to what end? Tkinter already has a perfectly usable event loop. Why do you think you need to write your own? Perhaps if you can give a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish we can give you a decent answer.

Comment: your code indentation is messed up -- that code won't work as posted.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to accomplish is unclear, but it sounds like you misunderstand how GUI programming works in general and are just asking the wrong question. Generally speaking, If you think you need to poll for button presses rather than take advantage of the event loop you are doing it wrong.

So, the best answer to "how can I listen for a button and not run a function" is "you can't".  It's a bit like asking "how can I put this screw in the wall with a hammer?". You can, but it's not the right way to use the tool so for all practical purposes you can't and shouldn't be taught how to.

It seems to me you are making a guessing game, and I think you want the user to press the up or down button after each guess. is that correct? If so, why not just have the up and down buttons call a function that makes a single guess?

Comment: @jmeyer10 Iwould agree with this. For the example provided you are massively overengineering this. Just call a function and you're done. While there are circumstances where my solution is necessary (I'd still like the downvotes removed), this is really basic stuff.

Comment: i agree but in my program, there is no real event loop

Comment: @jmeyer10: what do you mean "there is no real event loop"? What do you think `root.mainloop()` is? *all* GUI programs have event loops. Not only are they for user events (button presses, etc) but that is how the widgets know to redraw themselves when windows are covered or uncovered, resized, etc. You have an event loop, so use it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a loop along the lines of `while not exiting` where exiting is declared False at the start and is toggled when quitting the application. Then in that loop you can put functions that check certain state and update other state. Each time round the loop it will run each of these functions. The magic is to make each of these functions fast enough that it seems like they're running constantly.

Comment: very bad advice. A GUI is already running a loop, the event loop. There's simply no reason to write your own infinite loop.

Comment: @Bryan sometimes you don't want to block the gui with long operations, and they turn out to be unavoidable. Then it comes in handy to be comfortable with making your own event loops. please remove my downvote.

Comment: @BiggAl: There are better solutions than this. I don't know if it's possible in python, but the generally-accepted approach in most languages is to spin up a new thread for the long-running background task.

Comment: @BiggAl I made the same mistake. I tried to start the program and it wouldn't start!

Comment: @Bryan I take it you haven't tried this in python or you would have run into the GIL, so then you need yo use processes, and so you need a more heavyweight way of communicating with them - most of the time you end up with at least one more event loop.

Comment: how does this fit into `egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect` ? This is a perfectly valid technique for certain situations, and the situation is not defind in the question.

Comment: @jmeyer10 what precisely did you try?

Comment: @BigAl: you are incorrect. I *have* tried it in python and I know from experience that having a pseudo-event-loop inside an event loop is not a very workable solution. At least, not the way you described it.

Comment: @Bryan Who said anything about it being inside the other event loop? You pass messages between the event loops to keep things separate. Even if there are other ways to do this I do not see that my answer - which does work, I've done it - deserves downvoting.

Comment: Now somebody please help instead of arguing.